# using jsoup with proguard closing force close

Tags: android, jsoup, proguard

**EDIT : MY PROGUARD VERSION IS 4.7**

Today I tried include `jsoup (version 1.7.1)` in my android application, but it is causing me a lot of troubles. When I exported the signed `apk` with `proguard` **turned on** everytime my application was facing force close issues, then i disabled `proguard` and exported the `apk` and it ran perfectly. Please help me. How can I solve the error? The stacktrace is as below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:107
6)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:56
9)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.void initialiseParse(java.lang.String,java.lang.
String,org.jsoup.parser.ParseErrorList)(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse(java.lang.String,
java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.ParseErrorList)(Unknown Source)
                            boolean process(org.jsoup.parser.Token)
at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse(java.lang.Str
ing,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.ParseErrorList)(Unknown Source)
                                boolean process(org.jsoup.parser.Token)
                                boolean process(org.jsoup.parser.Token,org.j
soup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState)
                                void transition(org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBui
lderState)
                                org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState state(
)
                                void framesetOk(boolean)
                                void maybeSetBaseUri(org.jsoup.nodes.Element
)
                                org.jsoup.nodes.Element insert(org.jsoup.par
ser.Token$StartTag)
                                org.jsoup.nodes.Element insert(java.lang.Str
ing)
                                void insert(org.jsoup.parser.Token$Comment)
                                void insert(org.jsoup.parser.Token$Character
)
                                boolean isElementInQueue(org.jsoup.helper.De
scendableLinkedList,org.jsoup.nodes.Element)
                                void popStackToClose(java.lang.String[])
                                void insertOnStackAfter(org.jsoup.nodes.Elem
ent,org.jsoup.nodes.Element)
                                void replaceInQueue(java.util.LinkedList,org
.jsoup.nodes.Element,org.jsoup.nodes.Element)
                                boolean inSpecificScope(java.lang.String,jav
a.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])
                                boolean inSpecificScope(java.lang.String[],j
ava.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])
                                boolean inScope(java.lang.String,java.lang.S
tring[])
                                void insertInFosterParent(org.jsoup.nodes.No
de)
at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse(java.lang.String,java.
lang.String)(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse(java.lang.String)(Unknown Sour
ce)
at com.my.package.name.BalCheck.void doLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang
.String)(Unknown Source)
                                     void checkBal()
                                     void echo(java.lang.String)
at com.my.package.name.BalCheck.void doCheckBalance(java.lang.String,ja
va.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
at com.my.package.name.SmsPage$CheckUltooBalance.java.lang.Void doInBac
kground(java.lang.Void[])(Unknown Source)
                                                      void onPostExecute(jav
a.lang.Void)
at com.my.package.name.SmsPage$CheckUltooBalance.java.lang.Object doInB
ackground(java.lang.Object[])(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.java.util.Map loadEntities(java.lang.String)(Unknown
 Source)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
```

Answer (score 45):

*The solution posted by @Erdem in a comment above seems to be the best one. I'm reposting it as an answer for visibility.*

Add the line below to your proguard file

```
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
```

This seems to be enough

Comment: Thanks - @android-newbie should probably accept it ;-)

Answer (score 30):

You can go to [jsoup with proguard](http://www.jormula.com/dev/2013/01/29/tutorial-how-to-solve-force-close-crash-using-jsoup-with-proguard-in-android/) to find answer, which is to add the following to `proguard-project.txt`:

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}
```

Comment: No need to keep everything. This is enough:

-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes

Comment: Life Saver...:)

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines in proguard-rules.txt

```
#Jsoup
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
```